# show values of json data by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have my data returned by Json but somehow I'm not able to print it out.

here is my `javascript`

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('select[name="country_id"]').on('change', function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
       var CountryId = $(this).val();
        if(CountryId) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('profilegetStateList') }}/'+encodeURI(CountryId),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                  // $('select[name="state_id"]').empty();
                  // $('select[name="state_id"]').empty().append('<option value='+ data +' selected>'+data+'</option>');
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="state_id"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
  });
```

I have tried `data` , `data->name`, `data['name']` all of them return `[object object]`

here is my console prints on `console.log(data);`

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array []

[…]
0: Object { id: 1, name: "ACEH", country_id: 101 }
1: Object { id: 16, name: "BALI", country_id: 101 }
2: Object { id: 15, name: "BANTEN", country_id: 101 }
.....
length: 32
__proto__: Array []
```

any idea?

Comment: It looks like it printed out in the console just fine. If you want it to print as a string, then maybe you can try JSON.stringify(data)?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath No. how?

Comment: `data` is an array of objects hence you have to loop over the objects as shown by Aswin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing your code, I think the commented code should be like

```
var options = '';
data.forEach(function(country) {
    options += '<option value='+ country.id +' selected>'+country.name+'</option>'
})
$('select[name="state_id"]').empty().append(options);
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around the id and encoding for the values. And all options will have the selected property set.

Comment: The issues are in my comment. I would let jQuery do the work to create proper markup: http://jsbin.com/loyoqukocu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

The data that you are consoling, is in array format.
You need to access each index of object.
Try this inside success function,

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++ ){

console.log('name-',i,'= ',data[i].name)

}
```

Comment: something like this returned `name- 0 =  ACEH
name- 1 =  BALI
name- 2 =  BANTEN
name- 3 =  BENGKULU`

Comment: Thats what we are printing,
try console.log(data[i])
inside for loop, you will loop through all the  objects inside your array.

Answer (score 0):

[object Object] is the default toString representation of an object in javascript.

If you want to know the properties of your object, just foreach over it like this:

```
for(var property in data) {
    alert(property + "=" + data[property]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
for(var property in data) {
   if(data[property]){
      console.log(data[property])
   }
}
```

Comment: return `4=undefined`

Comment: [mafortis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8490993/mafortis), I have updated answer

Comment: prints like: `Object { id: 1, name: "ACEH", country_id: 101 }`

Answer (score 0):

Cant Comment..  so here is an addition to @Aswin Ramesh:
Maybe remove the selected property from the options attributes and add it only to the first option. This was a mistake of the OP